# How come a standard (non-sudo) user can reboot my server?

Tags: linux, rhel-6

I have RHEL 6.5 installed in VMware Workstation. When any normal user logs into the the virtual RHEL 6.5 server and runs `reboot` command, the server is rebooted. Normally, only users having sudo access or root can run `reboot` commands, and it is executed successfully.

What could be the possible reason that a normal user can login and reboot the system?

Comment: How does your `/etc/sudoers` look like?

Comment: it looks like normal one.default setting defined then user and group access etc

Comment: What I meant was that you add the contents of that file to your question... Also, has this been like that all the time, or did you change anything? What groups is the user member of? Anything custom?

Comment: It was by chance I ran reboot as normal user and to my shock it worked. I believe it was there earlier also. In sudoers file no changes done.

Answer (score 1):

If a user belongs to a group that has access to the reboot binary he can reboot...

Look for the user group(s) and his permissions on those files.